# how to assign order in spinner selection android

Tags: android

i am able to show 4 spinner in my view ..now i want to assign the order to selection on spinner means if i had selected first spinner then only i can select 2nd spinner value otherwise it gives a alert message 
and so on..so how to assign order of selection for spinner??pls help me thanks a lot..
i am attaching my code below..

```
     ArrayList<String> aa=  MainMenu.ciudad1;
     final Spinner ct = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, aa);
     ct.setAdapter(adapter);
     **ct.setEnabled(false);**


         ArrayList<String> estado = MainMenu.estado1;


     final Spinner estaddo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner03);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapterestado = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,estado);
     estaddo.setAdapter(adapterestado);
     estaddo.setEnabled(false);
     ArrayList<String> barrio = MainMenu.barrio1;


     final Spinner barrio11 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner04);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapterbarrio = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, barrio);
     barrio11.setAdapter(adapterbarrio);
     **barrio11.setEnabled(false);**
         ArrayList<String> type = MainMenu.type;
         Spinner type1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adaptertype= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, type);
     type1.setAdapter(adaptertype);
     **type1.setEnabled(true);**

     type1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {           

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
             View view, int position, long id) 
           {
               Spinner type1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
               typeselected = (String)type1.getSelectedItem();
               estaddo.setEnabled(true);

               System.out.println("type selected............:" + typeselected);

           }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {


                }
 });
     ct.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {           

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
             View view, int position, long id) 
           {

                Spinner ct = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);
                cityselected = (String)ct.getSelectedItem();
                barrio11.setEnabled(true);

              System.out.println("city selected............:" + cityselected);

           }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
 });
```

//       Spinner estaddo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner03);

```
             estaddo.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {           

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
             View view, int position, long id) 
           {

               Spinner estaddo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner03);
               stateselected = (String)estaddo.getSelectedItem();
               ct.setEnabled(true);
               barrio11.setEnabled(false);
               System.out.println("state selected............:" + stateselected);


           }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
 });
    // Spinner barrio = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner04);
     barrio11.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {           

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
             View view, int position, long id) 
           {

               Spinner barrio = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner04);
              neighbourselected = (String)barrio.getSelectedItem();
              System.out.println("neighbour selected............:" + neighbourselected);


           }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `Spinners` `enabled = false` and on user selection of 1 Spinner

```
type1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {           

       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
         View view, int position, long id) 
       {
           Spinner type1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);


           typeselected = (String)type1.getSelectedItem();


         System.out.println("type selected............:" + typeselected);
         type2.setEnabled(true);

       }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
 });
```

and so on for every Spinner

Comment: @saurabh Agnihotri hi...why u set  type2.setEnabled(true);
in type1?

Comment: thanks for help,..and how can i give a alert msg if wrong order spinner is selected

Comment: I guess your second spinner to be type2 so in this case a user can only make choice from second spinner if he had selected 2nd one

Comment: If you set enabled = false for other spinner user is not able to select them so need of displaying any alert

Comment: @saurabh Agnihotri hi pls take a look in my updated code i initially set 3 spinner enabled(false) and 1 spinner true and then did as u said to me then also all the spinner are enabled means without clicking on  the spinner it executed "setOnItemSelectedListener"..why pls what to do now?

Comment: means it always executed ....onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
           View view, int position, long id){}  without selecting it manually

Comment: Although thats not possible but if it is then I would suggest to setSelectionListener() only when yoau are setting that particular spinner enabled hope this helps

Comment: I mean to say to set onclicklitener only when you are enabling that partical spinner like if you when you enable 2nd spinner then at that setSelectionListener() on spinner 2 not before that